# Launch command (phantomjs) with two arguments read from file

Tags: parallel-processing, phantomjs, gnu-parallel

I have a file that contains two strings in each row which are the two arguments to launch a command (phantomjs) from shell. I would use GNU parallel to launch my command for each row. Now, if I launch manually, I write:

```
./phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.it/ google.png
```

and everything works. But if I try with parallel, something goes wrong:

```
parallel --verbose -a myfile --no-run-if-empty ./phantomjs rasterize.js
```

this is output

```
./phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.it/\ google.png
./phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.anothersite.it/\ pic.png
Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]
  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"
Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]
  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"
```

and I can't understand why it doesn't work, and why in verbose mode (first two rows) after link there's `\` character.

cat -vet output:

```
http://www.google.it/ google.png$
http://www.anothersite.it/ pic.png$
$
$
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug with all those long paths, try symlinking them... `ln -s ./phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs phantomjs` and also `ln - s phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-i686/examples/rasterize.js rasterize.js`

Comment: edited. now paths is smaller

Comment: Have you got some weird characters in your file `myfile`? Can you run `cat -vet myfile` and paste output into your question?

Comment: pasted. But seems no strange character is inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close to the answer with `why in verbose mode (first two row) after link there's "\" character?`

GNU Parallel treats each line as a single argument and will quote any special characters (such as space). This is what you see. This is a feature - not a bug. It means that what ever you put on a single line it will be quoted correctly for use in the shell.

But you do not want the default behaviour. You want GNU Parallel to split the line into 2 arguments. Your column separator is space:

```
parallel --verbose -a myfile --colsep ' ' --no-run-if-empty ./phantomjs rasterize.js
```